# How to display sum of column using MongoDb in PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have one collection as name 'trade' with four columns and I am want to show sum of one column.
Let me know how to do that.

Column name:play_amount

I want to display sum of 'play_amount'.

I am tried to sum using aggregate but enable to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This need to do the trick:

```
db.trade.aggregate({$group:{_id:"Total" ,Sum:{$sum:"$play_amount"} }})
```